# Let $p \in R [x_1, \dots x_n ]$ show p is countinous $(R^n,Zariski) $ to $(R,Zariski)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

**Question:**
Let $p \in R[x_1 , \dots x_n ]$ show  p is continuous  $(R^n ,Zariski) \to (R,Zariski)$

**Thoughts:**  Zariski topology has to do with set $R^n$ where the polynomial is sent to zero. $R^n$ goes to $R$ through $p$ I want to say that $p$ goes to $0$. I am supposed to show that taken a open set in $R$ the preimage is open in the  $(R^n ,Zariski)$

Comment: If $f\in R[x]$ and $p\in R\left[x_1,\ldots,x_n\right]$, then $f\big(p\left(x_1,\ldots,x_n\right)\big)\in R\left[x_1,\ldots,x_n\right]$.  You can instead show that the preimage of a Zariski-closed subset of $R$ under $p$ is a Zariski-closed subset of $R^n$.

Comment: What is $R$?  An algebraically closed field?

Comment: @D_S. I think the OP wanted to write $\mathbb{R}$, although the statement seems to hold for any commutative, not necessarily unital, ring $R$.  At least, maybe due to my ignorance, I haven't heard of the Zariski topology on a noncommutative ring.